# Using Logstash on Laravel

Tags: laravel, logstash

I would like to configure things so that whenever I make a `Log::info` or similar method call, it gets piped into Logstash. I've searched the net, but there's no clear examples. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a year later, I've learnt enough about how the Elastic stack works to answer this. Logstash is just a processing tool, which lives on its own host. You need to have an extraction tool to send logs to Logstash. My best suggestion would be to use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) and [configure a "beats" input for Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html).